# Bayes factors in R for correlated proportions (such as a "Bayesian McNemar's test")

Tags: r, bayesian, proportion, paired-data, bayes-factors

Is there any way to get Bayes factors in R for correlated proportions (i.e., paired sample)?

For example, the same group of 90 people is measured with one technique, then with another; once there are 50 positive findings (with 40 negative), and once 70 positive (with 20 negative). With a frequentist approach, I could use McNemar's test to compare the two techniques - but what do I use for Bayes factors?

A previous related question and answer is here: [Bayes Factors for McNemar Test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265837/bayes-factors-for-mcnemar-test)

However, these solutions are rather complex and not implemented in R (as far as I know).

I know that the `BayesFactor` package has the `contingencyTableBF` function for independent proportions, but not for correlated ones.